# Generating type definitions from .protobuf file using ts-protoc-gen results with just raw interfaces definitions except jspb.Message prototypes

Tags: typescript, protocol-buffers, protoc, protobuf.js

I am using **protobuf** library in order to generate code for data structures shared between platforms.
One of these platforms is nodejs, I use typescript on top of that. So besides protoc compiler (https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/javascript-generated) I use also **ts-protoc-gen** plugin (https://github.com/improbable-eng/ts-protoc-gen) in order to generate type definitions in order to use static typing for generated code.

ts-protoc-gen should generate not only simple interfaces definitons, but actual classes definition based on Messages defined in .proto file. I've generated type definitions for one of the plugin examples orphan.proto. 
https://github.com/improbable-eng/ts-protoc-gen/blob/master/proto/orphan.proto
Provided result which should be generated eg. for OrphanMessage looks like this:

```
export class OrphanMessage extends jspb.Message {
  getMyString(): string;
  setMyString(value: string): void;

  getMyBool(): boolean;
  setMyBool(value: boolean): void;

  getMyEnum(): OrphanEnumMap[keyof OrphanEnumMap];
  setMyEnum(value: OrphanEnumMap[keyof OrphanEnumMap]): void;

  serializeBinary(): Uint8Array;
  toObject(includeInstance?: boolean): OrphanMessage.AsObject;
  static toObject(includeInstance: boolean, msg: OrphanMessage): OrphanMessage.AsObject;
  static extensions: {[key: number]: jspb.ExtensionFieldInfo<jspb.Message>};
  static extensionsBinary: {[key: number]: jspb.ExtensionFieldBinaryInfo<jspb.Message>};
  static serializeBinaryToWriter(message: OrphanMessage, writer: jspb.BinaryWriter): void;
  static deserializeBinary(bytes: Uint8Array): OrphanMessage;
  static deserializeBinaryFromReader(message: OrphanMessage, reader: jspb.BinaryReader):
}
```

(source https://github.com/improbable-eng/ts-protoc-gen/blob/master/examples/generated/proto/orphan_pb.d.ts)

but result which i get is just a raw interface which in fact is not compatible with generated .js code in _pb.js file due to different styling.

```
export interface OrphanMessage {
    my_string?: string;
    my_bool?: boolean;
    my_enum?: OrphanEnum;
}
```

Do anybody have an idea why I'm not getting jspb.Message prototypes as a result?
I use following command to generate .js code with type definitions

```
protoc --plugin="/protoc-gen-ts=${PROTOC_GEN_TS_PATH}" --js_out="import_style=commonjs,binary:%TARGET_PATH%" --ts_out=%TARGET_PATH% %SOURCE_PROTO_FILE_NAME%.proto
```

Comment: I have the same question, do you resolve it ?